# C# MLApp Feval Variable Number of Arguments

Tags: c#, matlab, reflection, com

I am using a COM component to run Matlab code from a c# app.

Within this I am using the Feval function which has the following form:

```
matlab.Feval("MatlabFunction", 1, out result, param1, param2...., paramN);
```

Having the parameters passed in like this isn't very ideal as I would like to have one function matlabExecutor which can run any function but because of the way Feval takes in parameters it looks as though I will need to have a wrapper function per Matlab function.

Note: Yes I can pass in an array as a parameter but that would mean changing ALL of my Matlab scripts which I don't particularly want to do.

I've given reflection a quick go but couldn't seem to work out how to use it with a COM object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what are you trying to do, but here is another way to pass parameters without the need of a wrapper, using `cell`. It works for regular matlab functions, I am not sure if it works in your case.

```
params = {param1,param2,...paramN};
% works with plot
plot(params{:});

% just a guess, it might works
matlab.Feval("MatlabFunction", 1, out result, params{:});
```

Comment: I want to do this in C# .net, if I do what you have done it simply passes that whole cell array as the first input parameter.

Comment: I guess the issue is with the Feval matlab function that takes multiple parameters and cannot take an array instead.

Comment: Actually in Matlab, when i pass in the params as a cell array, each cell will be one input parameter for whatever Matlab function. It is quite similar to the use of `varargin` in matlab (which is also a cell array). I dont really understand your problem (im clueless about COM, .NET) so i can not assist you further. But i think this piece of information might help.

Comment: Yes you are correct but if you try and use your solution using Feval it doesn't work, it puts the whole cell array as one parameter:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feval.html

Comment: Hmm, I have tried an example with `feval('plot',params{:});` and it works

Comment: Apologies you are correct!

Not sure I can translate that to C# for some reason though, thank you though you have been helpful

Comment: Can you put your arguments into an array and pass the array as a single parameter? I've passed variable sized arrays into the MLAP COM object with no problems.